# Помогите сделать grid сетку

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Полный чайник в Grid CSS. Нужно на скорях сделать вот такую сетку.
Обшарил весь интернет, именно такой не нашёл.

[image: Grid сетка]

Кусок html кода

```
<div class="frontproject-item-list">
<a class="frontproject-item-inner foobox" href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
<a class="frontproject-item-inner foobox" href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
<a class="frontproject-item-inner foobox" href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
<a class="frontproject-item-inner foobox" href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
<a class="frontproject-item-inner foobox" href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
<a class="frontproject-item-inner foobox" href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.gallery__item {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 6;
}

.gallery__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 6 / 14;
}

.gallery__item:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.gallery__item:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 5 / 9;
}

.gallery__item:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 5 / 9;
}

.gallery__item:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 9 / 14;
}

.gallery__img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

<div class="gallery">
  <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" class="gallery__item" data-fancybox>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" class="gallery__item" data-fancybox>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" class="gallery__item" data-fancybox>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" class="gallery__item" data-fancybox>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" class="gallery__item" data-fancybox>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" class="gallery__item" data-fancybox>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/640" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Долгих лет вам жизни добрый человек :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT. использовал первый попавшийся генератор